# Add a custom text under featured products price in Woocommerce product widget

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, widget, product

I am trying to add a line of text under the price of my featured products on my homepage. 
I have tried editing the content-widget-product.php so it looks like this -

```
if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    exit;
}

global $product;

if ( ! is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
    return;
}

?>
<li>
    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_widget_product_item_start', $args ); ?>

    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $product->get_permalink() ); ?>">
        <?php echo wp_kses_post( $product->get_image() ); ?>
        <span class="product-title"><?php echo esc_html( $product->get_name() ); ?></span>
    </a>

    <?php if ( ! empty( $show_rating ) ) : ?>
        <?php echo wp_kses_post( wc_get_rating_html( $product->get_average_rating() ) ); ?>
    <?php endif; ?>

    <?php echo wp_kses_post( $product->get_price_html() ); ?>
    <p class="deliveryline">DELIVERY THROUGHOUT GREATER CAPE TOWN AREA</p>

    <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_widget_product_item_end', $args ); ?>
</li>
```

I added the "Delivery throughout line"... but it doesn't do anything though. Can someone please tell me why it's not working. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code that will add your custom text to the widget Products items for featured products only under the price in the home page:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_widget_product_item_end', 'home_widget_features_products', 10, 1 );
function home_widget_features_products( $args ){
    global $product;

    // Featured product on home page (when using the loop)
    if( $product->is_featured() && is_front_page() )
        echo '<p class="deliveryline">' . __("DELIVERY THROUGHOUT GREATER CAPE TOWN AREA", "woocommerce") . '</p>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

---

**Addition:** If you use a shortcode in your home page like for example:

```
[products limit="3" columns="3" visibility="featured"]
```

You will use the following code *(that works for products in the loop)*:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'home_loop_features_products', 20 );
function home_loop_features_products(){
    global $product;

    // Featured product on home page (when using the loop)
    if( $product->is_featured() && is_front_page() )
        echo '<p class="deliveryline">' . __("DELIVERY THROUGHOUT GREATER CAPE TOWN AREA", "woocommerce") . '</p>';
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (active theme). Tested and works.

[image]

---

**To display this custom text everywhere for all products** *(in all Woocommerce archive pages as shop and in all Woocommerce loops as related products, upsells, cross-sells…)*

You will use the same code without the if statement:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_products_loop', 20 );
function woocommerce_products_loop(){
    global $product;

    echo '<p class="deliveryline">' . __("DELIVERY THROUGHOUT GREATER CAPE TOWN AREA", "woocommerce") . '</p>';
}
```

Comment: oh great... Thanks!! i left the content-widget-product.php the way it was above... and pasted this into my function.php page, but it doesn't work :( am i doing something wrong? the url is https://flowersforeveryone.feedmybeta.com

Comment: @Michelle On your link it doesn't seem that you are using any Product widget on your home page, but a text widget with a shortcode maybe. So you should try my 2nd code instead that works on any products loop (even shortcode or others). My code target only the home page (just as you need). If it doesn't work, Try to show us a screen shot of the related widget settings.

Comment: ohh it works! Thank you!! What if i want this text on every page the product is located... e.g the home page and the category pages? Also, is there a way to get the text just underneath the price? Thanks

Comment: @Michelle So you want that on all pages like archives (shop, product category pages), related products, upsells, cross-sells? But only for featured products? or for all products?

Comment: yes please.. everywhere the product is displayed with the title, star rating and price like that and for all products.

Comment: Also, I want to put a line underneath that that says 'next possible delivery is' and then some logic that says if it's a business day before 12pm, it will say 'tomorrow' otherwise if it's after 12pm it will be the day after tomorrow.. so either displayed as "tomorrow" or the name of the next weekday. If possible please!!

Comment: @Michelle **Addition:** The last code will display the text everywhere for all products on all product loops. Now for the rest, you should better ask a new question providing all the necessary details and the conditional logic code to be used…